# Trying to delete column from table using Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, schema

I misspelled a word for a column and migrated the error, now I'm trying to delete the mistake from the schema and it doesn't seem that easy to do. I've deleted it out of the model and the schema by hand but it still shows up in the Rails Console when I make any changes to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont edit the schema by hand.

```
rake db:rollback
```

delete the migration file

recreate the migration correctly this time

```
rake db:migrate
```